# Dynamically add dijit date text boxes

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo, dijit.form

```
<label for="date1">Drop down Date box:</label>
<input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" value="2005-12-30"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox"
    required="true" />
```

What happens: The third statement doesnt work for me and what I get in result is a simple text box. 
Whats required: I want to get a x number of date text boxes. Where x is retrieved from database.

Comment: What dojo version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You have a mix of the old dojo declarative syntax and the newer html5 compatible syntax. The "data-" piece is used for the newer html5 syntax.

As pointed out by OammieR, you also don't use the "/" in the declaration and it should be a ".". See below for example.

```
<input id="date1" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
    data-dojo-props="required:true,name:'date1',value:'2005-12-30'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
<input type="text" 
                                   placeholder="Date of Birth"
                                   name="date" 
                                   dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
                                   required="true" 
                                   >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [new version(AMD)](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/modern_dojo/). When *require* you have to use `xxx/xxx/xxxx`

but in `data-dojo-type` you have to use `xxx.xxx.xxx` instead.

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/vzbVf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem and get this solution.  Before using AMD syntax in declarative you have to require module which is used to create widgets like:-

In your case first  you have to require widget

```
require(["dojo/parser","dijit/form/DateTextBox"],function(parser,DateTextBox)
{
    parser.parse();
});
```

as your creating widget declarative your have to parse your code also.

In HTML:-

```
<label for="date1">Drop down Date box:</label>
<input type="text" name="date1" id="date1" value="2005-12-30"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox"
    required="true" />
```

Now your free to use either xxx/xxx/xxxx or xxx.xxx.xxxx.
I hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you are using dojo AMD then below is the code to add a dijit DateTextBox dynamically.

```
  require(["dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/dom-construct",  "dojo/domReady!"],function(DateTextBox, domConstruct)
    {
        var parentNode = domConstruct.create("div", { "class": "container" }, mainContainer); // place this container in your main conatainer.
        var Date = new DateTextBox({
                name="date1",
                id="date1",
                value="2005-12-30"
              }, parentNode);          
        });
```

**Note:** if you are creating this in loop or multiple date picket at a time take care of **id** because id should be unique and should not be repeated.

Hope this will help you :)